# Wordpress: Show Plugins in front page post summaries?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a slider plugin and I am trying to get the plugin to appear on the post on the front page. unfortunately, it seems to be blocking it in some way? if I post text after the slider the text appears but not the slider before it. It seems not to be exclusive to this slider plugin either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excerpt feature of wordpress does not support images or anything other than text. you must edit the themes index.php or content.php page to show "the_content" rather than "the_excerpt".